# Google Maps API v1 on Android 5 not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using Google Maps API v1 on Android. However, the background of my Maps is not displayed on my Nexus 5 running API 22. Does Google Maps API v1 even work on Android 5?

In my manifest I have

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

I read that you need an API key somewhere? Where do I need to specify that.

The logcat output is:

```
W/System.err﹕ IOException processing: 26
W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
W/System.err﹕ at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
W/System.err﹕ at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.processDataRequest(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1117)
W/System.err﹕ at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher.serviceRequests(DataRequestDispatcher.java:994)
W/System.err﹕ at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher$DispatcherServer.run(DataRequestDispatcher.java:1702)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/CursorWrapperInner﹕ Cursor finalized without prior close()
W/CursorWrapperInner﹕ Cursor finalized without prior close()
W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 8.609ms
```

Comment: simple answer.. you should use api v2

Comment: The app is built on v1. The question is why all of a sudden the backgrounds are missing in my maps.

Comment: Any relevant logcat output when you run on a lollipop device?

Comment: Updated logcat in my answer

Comment: just move on to Api v2, follow the guide and if you have problems again let us know how we can help with separate question

Answer (score 3):

First things first.. You should use API v2 .. Here you have details about getting started https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

@barq The reason for that is that Google Maps **API v1 is deprecated long time ago**. You should'n use it any more, you shouldn't focus on problem related to it, because you are lying yourself and users that you are supporting Lollipop when you are using api deprecated few years ago. You need to move on so this kinda things doesn't happen when you want to support new version of OS. That v1 api is not replace without reason and it can disappear, be removed tomorrow! No further notice.

It doesn't make sense to look for solution for this when you shouldn't use it. That is the reason I linked description of how to move on. Moderators should close this for further discussion to avoid making more noise about old api that nobody use anymore.

If you have problems with new API post a new question and we will be really happy to help with that.

Comment: v1 was deprecated 3 years ago. Any good reason why this was down voted? It is the most sensible answer. +1

Comment: @barq Deprecation means it is no longer supported could go away at any time. It could have been immediate, 1 year or 5 years when they announced it but Google clearly gave notice. Same situation exists with Apache HTTP client http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html. If and when Google announces a Android Maps API v3 - migration/replacement is the only solution.

Comment: While in general I agree with you, on this particular occasional I think this is not the case. The documentation clearly states that "apps using v1 will continue to work on devices". See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Comment: @barq I stand corrected, it looks like they had a 3 year depreciation window and appears to be 1 year now. They should change the V1 documentation to point to their depreciation policy https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_4_4 since we are past the 3 years mentioned for breaking changes to service in their original blog post: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html

Comment: The problem was actually the API key. With release builds the maps show fine. However, with debug builds, the maps are grey, and since Google is no longer giving out keys for v1 I cannot get a debug key for v1.

Comment: so once again conclusion: Don't use deprecated api. Don't ask question about deprecated api because somebody (who shouldn't use api v1) will land here and spend time reading about "solution" and by reading this he is wasting time